# Python NetworkX/Mplleaflet: network to geojson

Tags: javascript, python, html, geojson, networkx

I've been using `networkx` and `mplleaflet` to plot my network from nx on a leaflet map. Using my one of my smaller data sets, this works perfectly. However, it doesn't scale with larger data. Is it possible to either export my graph form `networkx` to a geojson or extract the geojson created with `mplleaflet` into a new file? I know graphs/ nodes/edges in `networkx` can be written to a json, but my network contains vital geographic information, and since `mplleaflet` can't handle the size, I'd like to import it into QGIS.

**Edit**

A leaflet map made with one of my smaller data sets can be located here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1lvsCnLWydEQ2ZkSS1XZ09TOFk

Viewing the html file itself I can see the data is, as expected, stored as a geojson. I tried a simple copy and paste of the data but that doesn't work because it is a *lot* of features, and it is also not correctly formatted. I am not familiar with `html`, or `javascript`, and do not know how to extract the information from the file - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an effort to answer my own question after over a year, I identified the closest possible solution to this using SQL and PostGIS/CARTO, rather than Python and `networkx` (unfortunately). Using `ST_MakeLine`, ordering the points/nodes (latitude/longitude) by ascending timestamp, and then grouping by unique identifier, a result similar to these can be achieved:

[image: https://carto.com/blog/jets-and-datelines/]
(https://carto.com/blog/jets-and-datelines/)

[image]
(https://carto.com/blog/alteryx-and-carto-to-explore-london-bike-data/)

Performing this type of analysis in a CARTO database allows for scalability and can easily be incorporated into a custom web map and further developed (with JavaScript) beyond simple plotting with mplleaflet.